# Setting it to IL2CPP in unity causes an error when packaging Android packages

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

**Setting it to IL2CPP in unity causes an error when packaging Android packages,but I couldn't use Mono because the AR Foundation mandates IL2CPP，unity is 2022.3.3，Is there any other solution?**

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\iz17e\libil2cpp.so failed with output:

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_getEnabled
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17104 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17104)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_get_Enabled_m673D073E4B6EF6D5266CA635B238B849AA0C1BAB)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17104 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17104)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_GetEnabled_m0F8E2DB79BA38E67F73C37AC896CC71BF41B513D)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_setEnabled
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17097 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17097)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_set_Enabled_mBEA2BE949320C83A1F01DEB8F19C2CC9420BD6EF)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17097 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17097)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_SetEnabled_mDA05621506EC33993DE6CE32213C31A35B0AFF2D)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSString_createWithString
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18335 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18335)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession__ctor_m48D4CF11A5FF84874EBBB812B176F36DAFA5942D)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18335 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18335)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession__ctor_m48D4CF11A5FF84874EBBB812B176F36DAFA5942D)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18335 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18335)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString__ctor_mA318947583C2A7E09C9BA6226BDF43B5158EEB38)
>>> referenced 1 more times

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_initWithName
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17065 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17065)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession__ctor_m48D4CF11A5FF84874EBBB812B176F36DAFA5942D)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17065 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17065)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_InitWithName_mB47809B8068161BF69CF80ACB4C61E7380C10586)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_CFRelease
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17130 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17130)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession__ctor_m48D4CF11A5FF84874EBBB812B176F36DAFA5942D)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17130 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17130)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession__ctor_m48D4CF11A5FF84874EBBB812B176F36DAFA5942D)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17130 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17130)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession__ctor_m48D4CF11A5FF84874EBBB812B176F36DAFA5942D)
>>> referenced 18 more times

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_sendToAllPeers
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17057 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17057)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_SendToAllPeers_m6EB10E329F60B747EC5087661D983F10A456D04A)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17057 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17057)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_SendToAllPeers_m05D206ED560D05F8D35C42F57ABAC0BDDCCC2669)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_receivedDataQueueSize
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17073 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17073)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_get_ReceivedDataQueueSize_mDDC0D2DCAB5A034D19140D2433F817D3C89ED095)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17073 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17073)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_GetReceivedDataQueueSize_m270753069757F4DDE1315FD34BD6195AF6124099)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17073 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17073)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_get_ReceivedDataQueueSize_mDDC0D2DCAB5A034D19140D2433F817D3C89ED095_AdjustorThunk)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_dequeueReceivedData
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17081 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17081)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_DequeueReceivedData_mBB5F068CA03E86FF2938B44A0505B268FB2CB3C0)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17081 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17081)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_DequeueReceivedData_mB68CCB7C0CC97AB9E5C1415A7612D84C2DFD98A8)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_Delegate_connectedPeerCount
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17089 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17089)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_get_ConnectedPeerCount_m70616D202D0143009D03082849EEC89FE1916F20)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17089 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17089)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_GetConnectedPeerCount_m889159CC4C0302AE0C6DC8A5D16BFE594BB6934B)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17089 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17089)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(MCSession_get_ConnectedPeerCount_m70616D202D0143009D03082849EEC89FE1916F20_AdjustorThunk)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSData_getLength
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17517 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17517)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_get_Length_mEBB4C8B5555F7954422F29D171C50B3289D76818)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17517 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17517)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_GetLength_m18870E8FA9B7121546844048DB0B2844349CC8FB)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17517 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17517)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_get_Bytes_mBE59E96595CE3B99959DBE8C1F049A58C9C3B1BA)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSData_createWithBytes
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17533 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17533)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_CreateWithBytes_mB533684C3677743B4FF081F29D2B434767C2237E)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17533 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17533)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_CreateWithBytes_m9ACDA1908385AE95805AE95663A33063AD4B5EC6)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSData_createWithBytesNoCopy
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17541 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17541)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_CreateWithBytesNoCopy_mE60F3EE91D54AF799F120E2321AA0387E15B7F08)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17541 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17541)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_CreateWithBytesNoCopy_mB7116AA642F24E05CC717E682CDB1C618301CCA7)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSData_getBytes
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17525 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17525)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_get_Bytes_mBE59E96595CE3B99959DBE8C1F049A58C9C3B1BA)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17525 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17525)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSData_GetBytes_m675068905E6D0AEB2634D33998FF660D1EE78910)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSError_code
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17853 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17853)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSError_get_Code_m609DF72AC6A07397FA97A5B38D645FFB20EEF017)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17853 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17853)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSError_GetCode_m08024CB17028A1274EA7AC9399DCCD0B0448946B)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSError_localizedDescription
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17861 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17861)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSError_get_Description_m29BC067719FABFF453B9284C5D5EE0D52FBE2ED0)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17861 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:17861)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSError_GetLocalizedDescription_m2F66521E246FC066B9DAF54D0D468199C60C435A)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSString_lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18343 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18343)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_ToString_mD500269B96D231006A03AB55108D862FFF3F1926)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18343 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18343)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_GetLengthOfBytes_m56E659D320AC220C7F92B2A26CD59A9E9D89A199)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSString_getBytes
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18359 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18359)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_ToString_mD500269B96D231006A03AB55108D862FFF3F1926)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18359 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18359)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_GetBytes_m4D966C0430053F000B1EA0FE1D1F14260E6201F4)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSString_getLength
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18351 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18351)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_ToString_mD500269B96D231006A03AB55108D862FFF3F1926)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18351 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18351)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_get_Length_mDF085BC7DFC46412427E8F68F92BD47739BF1DEF)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18351 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18351)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_GetLength_m12CFED74B3771A60877D978EAAA025612EE93B28)
>>> referenced 1 more times

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSString_deserialize
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18375 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18375)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString__ctor_m2F90CA5D483D287149AFB3143528E2F472FA2F4E)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18375 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18375)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_Deserialize_m633254993101859F460428DF408E66CA9C6DDCBA)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: UnityMC_NSString_serialize
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18367 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18367)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_Serialize_m11682E0AE3634B4B1048F8D05B3F9FCECB3F2D8E)
>>> referenced by Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18367 (E:/ARFoundationTest/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp\Assembly-CSharp__2.cpp:18367)
>>>               Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/fpz2p25i7upk.o:(NSString_Serialize_mF8667D09C23F9B03016EFCDF5B2429A00FD88AD2)
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

There was an attempt to delete library and reload, but to no effect

Comment: Why does Android need functions such as NSString? What is UnityMC? This should be an iOS plugin so you need to exclude it from your build.